# Coupled second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I  need to solve a coupled system of linear second order differential equations of the form:

$$a_1x''+b_1x'+c_1x+d_1y=0$$

$$a_2y''+b_2y'+c_2y+d_2x=0$$

Initial conditions are :

$$y(0)=y_0+y'(0),\quad y'(H)=0,\quad x(0)=x_0+x'(0),\quad x'(H)=0.$$
x and y are displacement in height.

This system shows the balance in chemical system between the concentration of gas phase and liquid phase.

What method do you suggest for solving this system? Analytical solution? Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I mean this could be suuuper overkill but worst-case scenario I know you can turn this into a first order system with the substitutions $s = x', t = x'', u = y', v = y'',$ and then you can solve with the standard first-order linear system methods.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,  do you any how to get the anylitical solution especially that the initial condition is confusing

Comment: Okay well first off sorry but I just realized I screwed up a bit, only two new variables should be necessary, so let $s = x', t = y'.$ As for the initial conditions, I can't quite say because I don't exactly understand the conditions given in the question, can you clarify that?

Comment: The initial condition is x(0)=X0+X(0)'    X0 IS GIVEN AND X(0)' IS DERVETIVE OF THE FUNCTION X AT 0 and x(H)=0 H is given height and so on for y

Comment: Got it, well that should be doable by just plugging in $0$ into your general homogeneous solution and each condition will give you an equation, so you'll get a 4 by 4 linear system back in terms of your four arbitrary constants. You're familiar with how to solve $\vec{r}' = A\vec{r}$ yeah?

Comment: Ok I will try, do u have any idea how to solve it matlab?

Comment: I think the best way to go about that would likely be to use the matrix exponential, expm. Because then if you can write a system as $\vec{r}' = A\vec{r},$ the general solution can be written as $\vec{r} = \vec{c}e^{At}.$ Alternatively you can use the eig function to have matlab calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for you, if you prefer that approach.

Answer (score 0):

The generic strategy is to look for solutions of the form
\begin{align}
x=A e^{\lambda t}\, ,\qquad y=B e^{\lambda t} \tag{1}
\end{align}
for some unknowns $\lambda, A$ and $B$.  Note that the exponential is common to both $x$ and $y$.

Inserting the ansatz into your system will give a linear system of the form
\begin{align}
M\left(\begin{array}{c} A \\ B\end{array}\right)=0 \tag{2}
\end{align}
where $M$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix with entries depending on the coefficients of your system *and on $\lambda$*:
\begin{align}
M=\left(\begin{array}{cc}a_1\lambda^2+b_1\lambda+c_1& d_1\\
d_2&a_2\lambda^2+b_2\lambda+c_2\\
\end{array}\right)
\end{align}  Since both $x$ and $y$ have the same time dependence, the exponential factor $e^{\lambda t}$ will drop out of (2).

To avoid the trivial solution $A=B=0$, the matrix $M$ cannot have an inverse, so its determinant must be $0$.  The condition Det$(M)=0$ while produce a quartic equation in $\lambda$.  You then need to check if all the roots are physical (or, rather, “chemical” in this case).  For each root you will get a different ratio of $A$ and $B$.  The general solution will then be a linear combination of the type
\begin{align}
x&= \sum_i A_ie^{\lambda_i t}\, ,\qquad y=\sum_i B_i e^{\lambda_i t}
\end{align}
with the coefficients $A_i$ to be determined from the initial conditions, and the $B_i$ determined from (2) as a function of $A_i$ once you insert $\lambda_i$ in (2).

Comment: thank you for your answer ,when i tried to get Ai from initial  condition  , I get four equation with with eight  unknown  , Bi will show when solving from initial condition.

Comment: The ratios $B_i/A_i$ are fixed by inserting $\lambda_i$ in (2), so you will be left with $4$ unknowns (the $4$ $A_i$’s), and you have 4 initial conditions.

Comment: but the number of B is 4 and A is 4 for example A1,A2,A3,A4 and B1, B2,B3, B4   and the solution for quartic equation is λ1,λ2,λ3 λ4 beside the initial condition x(0)=x0+x′(0), there is no value ,  I am confused , and what about the particular solution and all the roots are real?

Comment: The $B_1$, $B_2$, $B_3$ and $B_4$ are determined by the $A_1, A_2$ etc.  When you insert $\lambda_1$ into (2), this forces relations between $B_1$ and $A_1$ so the $B_i$'s are *completely* determined from the $A_i$'s.  You *cannot* choose the $B_i$'s independently from the $A_i$'s.

Comment: Ok I got you,in this case I can solve it without initial condition,because I have 8 equations from (2) 
, what about the particular solution, and do you any idea how to do in matlab?